# Rails installation on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails for last 4 month. But Problem is whenever i got time my all time got waste to try to install it in my Mac Machine. It's easy to install in window only by a single installer. But in mac i try many combination of Ruby and Rails versions. But not able to run it. Always getting different types of errors like 'Could not find gem sqlite3-ruby (>= 0) ruby' or Bundle installer, etc.

I know this types of problem is discussed in many forms. I follow many of them but problem is still there. Can someone please give me a permanent solution of my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) is your friend :)

Just one command to install Ruby, Rails both :)

```
 curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

**Optional other things:**

You may want to see [JewelryBox](http://unfiniti.com/software/mac/jewelrybox)

Comment: @Tarun to be on safe side, I will suggest yes. Remove the previous rvm etc. Here is the quick and perfect way to do it :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558763/179855

Comment: Thanks. My problem is almost solved only for two small commands rvm implode and curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails as you said. Now only have a small problems is Whenever I'm creating a new project it'll take some time to install bundle. Also when i start server it's take lot of time :(

Answer (score 2):

[Rails New](https://rails.new/) is your new friend ;)
It comes default with **rbenv** and other dependencies, and is the fastest way to setup rails on MAC.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://rails.new/✨)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on this a few months back. Everything should still be relevant. http://matthalliday.ca/weblog/entry/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-environment